# How can I hide/unhide a set of divs based on the clicking of an image

Tags: javascript, html

Hello there and thanks in advance for your help.

I have working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/wmbice/hy7xLv5f/2/ that provides the ability to change the visibility of a div based on the selection of a fruit from a drop down menu. I would like to be able to use the same method of determining visibility by selecting one of 3 pictures instead of using the drop down menu.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="triggerAnimation animated" data-animate="fadeInDown">
        <h2>FRUIT AREA<br>
                   Apples - Oranges - Lemons</h2>

    <select size="1" id="reportsSelect">
        <option value="blank" onclick="show(this)">Blank Div</option>
        <option value="apples" onclick="show(this)">Apples</option>
        <option value="oranges" onclick="show(this)">Oranges</option>
        <option value="lemons" onclick="show(this)">Lemons</option>
    </select>
    <div id="blankDiv" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="applesDiv" style="display:none;">
         <h1>Apples</h1>

        <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="orangesDiv" style="display:none;">
         <h1>Oranges</h1>

        <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
        <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="lemonsDiv" style="display:none;">
         <h1>Lemons</h1>

        <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
        <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
        <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END .triggerAnimation, .animated, .col-sm-4 -->
```

...and here is the Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    // Trigger hidden div   
    $.fn.showField = function () {
        var selectVal = document.getElementById(this.val() + 'Div');
        return this.each(function () {
            $(selectVal).show().siblings('div').hide();
        });
    };
    $('select#reportsSelect').change(function () {
        $(this).showField();
    });
});
```

Any recommendations will be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using jQuery `.on` click function:

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
    var fruitType = $(this)[0].id
    var showDivId = "#" + fruitType + "Div";
    $(showDivId).show().siblings('div').hide();
});

<img id="apples" src="http://bit.ly/1AcfNNQ">
<img id="oranges" src="http://bit.ly/19MlpVy">
<img id="lemons" src="http://bit.ly/1vx8QCV">
```

When a click event occurs on an `img` element, it will fire off this function - which finds the id of the element (the fruit name) and calls the show function and hides its siblings.

See the updated jsbin [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hy7xLv5f/4/)

Comment: Thank you bobdye and Dave Kerr! You both have provided me with what appears to be two excellent ways of doing this. While you both have used different  methods, do either one of you know which one is best, has the highest browser compatibiity, uses the fewest resources, etc? Is the difference negligible?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the trigger for your hidden divs as shown in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/0xstevnw/). I've created three dummy divs to take the place of images, each with a data attribute showing which hidden div they should display. I also added a class called details to your hidden divs so jQuery can easily select them.

The details can vary, but using this setup, the code is simply:

```
$(function () {
    // Trigger hidden div - Services    
    $('.likeimage').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var type = $this.attr('data-div');
        // Hide the previous
        $('.details').hide();
        $('#' + type + 'Div').show();
    });
});
```